# Python Hierarchical data structure with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, frameworks, metaprogramming, metaclass

I would to like to create a metaclass for a hierarchical data structure and write a framework for others to use.

I found this answer very helpful: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/162702/275475
It seems close to solving my problem, but if I inherit, for example, `Submodule` class, it will show assertion error at line: `assert isinstance(parent, self._parent_class)`

below is the code (copied from the answer in the link above and added my class defines)

```
class ModuleMetaClass(type):
    """ Metaclass that is instantiated once for each class """
    _metaclass_instances = None

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        if cls._metaclass_instances is None:
            # First instance is ModuleBaseClass
            cls._parent_class = None
            cls._metaclass_instances = [type(None)]
        else:
            # parent class is the previously declared class
            cls._parent_class = cls._metaclass_instances[-1]

            # if not at the top of the tree, then we are our parent's child
            if cls._parent_class != type(None):
                cls._parent_class._child_class = cls

            # store this class in the list of classes
            cls._metaclass_instances.append(cls)

        # no child class yet
        cls._child_class = None

        # call our base (meta) class init
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)


class ModuleBaseClass(metaclass=ModuleMetaClass):
    """ Base class for each of the derived classes in our tree """

    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        assert isinstance(parent, self._parent_class)
        self.name = name
        self._parent = parent

        if self._child_class is not None:
            self._children = {}

            # child class variable plural is used to add a common name
            plural = getattr(self._child_class, '_plural')
            if plural is not None:
                setattr(self, plural, self._children)

        # add self to our parents collection
        if parent is not None:
            parent._add_child(self)

        # add an access attribute for each of the nodes above us in the tree
        while parent is not None:
            setattr(self, type(parent).__name__.lower(), parent)
            parent = parent._parent

    def _add_child(self, child):
        assert isinstance(child, self._child_class)
        assert child.name not in self._children
        self._children[child.name] = child

# --------------------------------

class Module(ModuleBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name, lang):
        super().__init__(name, None)
        assert lang in ['fr', 'en']
        self.lang = lang

class Submodule(ModuleBaseClass):
    _plural = 'submodules'

class Ability(ModuleBaseClass):
    _plural = 'abilities'

class Template(ModuleBaseClass):
    _plural = 'templates'

    def __init__(self, name, ability):
        super().__init__(name, ability)
        self.lang = module.lang

# --------------------------------
# add my class defines

class MyModule(Module):
    pass

class MySubmodule(Submodule):
    pass


# --------------------------------
# changed instantiation to my class defines, then it would show the assertion error.

module = MyModule('module1', 'fr')
sub_module1 = MySubmodule('sub_module1', module)
sub_module2 = MySubmodule('sub_module2', module)
ability = Ability('ability1', sub_module1)
template = Template('template1', ability)
print(template.lang)
```

I checked `_metaclass_instances`, it is `[<class 'NoneType'>, <class '__main__.Module'>, <class '__main__.Submodule'>, <class '__main__.Ability'>, <class '__main__.Template'>, <class '__main__.MyModule'>, <class '__main__.MySubmodule'>]`, and `MyModule`'s parent class is `Template`, this is obviously not correct, but I have no idea how to modify the code.

Comment: your code is incorrect in that while it is possible to create an inheritance tree, some of your over-complicated data structures expect just a _line_ of sucession, not allowing, for example, more than one `_child_class` per class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you are trying to annotate things in different data structures, that not only are hard to follow, but also expect a linear inheritance (only one child to each class), when you actually have a tree: one class can have multiple children.

The fact is that Python *already* annotates all, or most, of this data automatically - there is no need for a metaclass at all in this case (and even if there is some custom annotation needed at class creation time, a `__init_subclass__` method should suffice in this case.

Parent classes to a class can be found in the `.__mro__` class attribute, and immediate subclasses to a class in the `.__subclasses__()` class method. If you don't want your final code to call those directly, you can use properties to get the values you want:

So, try this instead, without a metaclass - give or take marking the ends of your chain explicitly with a `None`:

```
class ModuleBaseClass:
    """ Base class for each of the derived classes in our tree """

    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        assert isinstance(parent, self._parent_class)
        self.name = name
        self._parent = parent

        if self._child_classes:
            self._children = {}

            # child class variable plural is used to add a common name
            plural = getattr(self._child_class, '_plural')
            if plural is not None:
                setattr(self, plural, self._children)

        # add self to our parents collection
        if parent is not None:
            parent._add_child(self)


        # add an access attribute for each of the nodes above us in the tree
        while parent is not None:
            setattr(self, type(parent).__name__.lower(), parent)
            parent = parent._parent
    
    
    @property
    def _parent_class(self):
        return type(self).__mro__[1]
    
    @property
    def _child_classes(self):
        return tuple(type(self).__subclasses__())

    def _add_child(self, child):
        assert isinstance(child, self._child_classes)
        assert child.name not in self._children
        self._children[child.name] = child
        
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._children[name]
        except KeyError as error:
            raise AttributeError from error

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.chilren)
```

I added the special `__getattr__`  and `__len__`  calls there, as I think they may be convenient to your use case.

Comment: Agreed that metaclass seems not needed. I didn't know `.__mro__` can be used to find parent class. Thanks!